# How to set scroll of UIWebView in phone gap?

Tags: uiwebview, cordova

Iam using Phone gap For developing Cross platform mobile application i just started it but i try to fixed the scroll of UIWebView its not working i try it through CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
html {height:250;}
body {height:250;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.ontouchmove = function(e){ e.preventDefault()};
```

this code Works For me :)